# Какое ключевое слово используется в производном классе для вызова конструктора класса-предка?

Tags: c#

Какое ключевое слово используется в производном классе для вызова конструктора класса-предка?

Comment: Играем в поле-чудес? base?:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это [ключевое слово `base`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Пример вызова базового конструктора:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    int num;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in BaseClass()");
    }

    public BaseClass(int i)
    {
        num = i;
        Console.WriteLine("in BaseClass(int i)");
    }

    public int GetNum()
    {
        return num;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // This constructor will call BaseClass.BaseClass()
    public DerivedClass() : base()
    {
    }

    // This constructor will call BaseClass.BaseClass(int i)
    public DerivedClass(int i) : base(i)
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass md = new DerivedClass();
        DerivedClass md1 = new DerivedClass(1);
    }
}
/*
Output:
in BaseClass()
in BaseClass(int i)
*/
```